# How to prove Integral result

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve a integral through `Mathematica`, `Mathematica` gives me the following answer

[image]

My question is how to solve this integral manually to get the `Mathematica` result or can we prove two integrals are equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute

$$z = \frac{w}{1-w} \iff w = \frac{z}{1+z}.$$

Then you have $dz = \frac{dw}{(1-w)^2}$, $1+z = (1-w)^{-1}$ and you obtain

$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty z^{-\frac{r}{\beta}}[1+z]^{-\frac{\alpha}{\gamma}-1}\,dz &= \int_0^1 \left(\frac{w}{1-w}\right)^{-\frac{r}{\beta}}[1-w]^{\frac{\alpha}{\gamma}+1}\,\frac{dw}{(1-w)^2}\\
&= \int_0^1 w^{-\frac{r}{\beta}}(1-w)^{\frac{r}{\beta}+\frac{\alpha}{\gamma}+1-2}\,dw.
\end{align}$$